# Simply command with parametres C parser

Tags: c, parsing

sorry for my english.
I need to write a simply parser in ANSI C for micorcontroller that receive as input a string like "command(param1, param2, param3...)" ad for output a string with the command and an array with the param.
The trouble is that I Always coded similar program in high-level Language like Java, and I haven't idea how can I make this parser in ANSI C.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Yes. A `C` teacher or a tutor can.

Comment: usual format for commands are key-value pairs, like `command -param1=1`, so that you have clear indicators of the locations of parameter name, value, and boundaries of key-value pair.

Answer (score 0):

String is an array of characters/numbers, so you can iterate through the array from byte to byte just like in Java and compare to specific characters (e.g. delimiters).

```
char ch0 = '(';    
char ch1 = ',';
if( ch0 != ch1 ) { /* .. */ }
```